# Breakpoint stop and shows wrong window in Xcode 8

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode8, breakpoints

I've added breakpoint in `ViewDidLoad` but when code execute and stop on breakpoint then it shows wrong window (Thread Window) instead of in Code.

[image: Breakpoint]

showing thread window

[image: thread window]

I've Xcode 8.3.3 and I think this may be some issue in setting or may be something else, kindly guide me where i did wrong ?

Looking for help. Thanks

Comment: Yes I can but thisn't worked I already tried.

Comment: Sorry Prakash this isn't worked also, any other try?

Comment: Its not crashing in app coz i run app without breakpoint working fine. I think problem is somewhere xcode settings, coz its was working fine but I downloaded xcode 9 and then remove xcode 9 after that the problem occurred.

Comment: Oh c'mon stop suggesting these attempt please.

Answer (score 0):

After hit and try I finally found solution, I did wrong and mistakenly check **Allow Show Disassembly**.
[image]

**Allow Show Disassembly** should be unchecked. 
Hope this will help others too.